# How to create a two-dimensional array from textbox with comma separated values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a html textbox with comma seperated values for example

name,age
name,age
name,age

and so on. The structure will always be the same.
Now i want to create an array where i can retrieve a specified value like:

array[1][0] (two-dimensional)

my code so far is:

```
//retrieve values from textbox
var lines = $('#area').val().split(/\n/);

//create an array   
    var texts = []
    for (var i=0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        // only push this line if it contains a non whitespace character.
        if (/\S/.test(lines[i])) {
            texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
        }
       if (/^[,]+$/.test(lines[i][i])) {
            texts.push($.trim(lines[i][i]));
        }

}
```

But this doesnt work.Does anyone have an idea how i can do this in javascript?
I am a beginner in Javascript :-)

**The goal should be to get all inputed names as an array and the age as well.**

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `textbox` don't allow multi-line, you might be referring to `textarea`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I meaned Textarea... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
texts.push($.trim(lines[i]));
```

To this:

```
 texts.push($.trim(lines[i]).split(","));
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hb18o802/)**</kbd>

Comment: @MichaelStrate you was almost there. It was just a simple detail.

Comment: One last question: Maybe you can point me in the right direction: How can I now retrieve by a loop the key of the array and create a new one only with the first entries (in this case only names)? I tried with this solution `test = []
 for(var i=0; i <= texts.length; i++){
 
  test.push(texts[i][0]);
  
 }` but it shows only **TypeError: test[i] is undefined**

Comment: If i alert the values like `Alert(texts[i][0])` than it works as intended but if i use `test[i] = texts[i][0];` OR `test.push(texts[i][0]);` than the log shows me the error message **TypeError: texts[i] is undefined**

Comment: @MichaelStrate so try `texts[0][0]`

Comment: Still not working. In PHP it is so easy to solve this issue but with Javascript...I dont like this Language :-) However, i have to find a solution to walk through the array by loop take only the first one (key) and put them into a new array in order to use it for further processing.. Assigining a Value from a multi array like array[i][0] in a loop seems not so easy in javascript like in PHP. DontVoteMeDown, if you don't have an idea don't put your self under pressure ;-) . I appreciate your help so far!!!

Comment: @MichaelStrate haha its ok. I disagree. In JS that should be easy to do as well in PHP, [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/hb18o802/1/). Is quite the same as you did you tried, but I don't know how it doesn't works. Tell me if that still isn't what you want.